# Creating 3-Way Data Tensor in Python and performing PARAFAC decomposition

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, data-science, tensor

I'm new to Python and Data Science and replicating a research paper I found on Vehicle Maintenance.

I'm trying to analyze vehicle maintenance data to find seasonal patterns in component maintenance over absolute time and also component maintenance patterns over the age of a vehicle. By component I mean a specific part.

I want to create a 3-way data tensor with vehicle number on the vertical axis, component number on the horizontal axis and the depth representing time(absolute or vehicle age).

Each element will represent the count of jobs performed on the component at a given vehicle number, component number and time.

I will appreciate it if someone can point me in the right direction to understand how to create a 3D tensor with the described data. The resources I've found so far deal with numpy matrices only, but my data is alpha numeric with the time unit being month.

Direction on available resources on PARAFAC decomposition in Python will also be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [TensorLy](https://tensorly.github.io/dev/index.html) which implements tensor operations, decompositions and regressions, and in particular, allows you to apply [PARAFAC](https://tensorly.github.io/dev/modules/generated/tensorly.decomposition.parafac.html#tensorly.decomposition.parafac) easily.

Also checkout the [notebooks](https://github.com/JeanKossaifi/tensorly-notebooks) for an introduction to tensor methods with TensorLy. There is also a chapter on tensor decomposition that includes Parafac and demonstrates how to apply it in practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [tensorlearn](https://pypi.org/project/tensorlearn/) package. Especially for [PARAFAC](https://github.com/rmsolgi/TensorLearn/tree/main/CP_decomposition) see the [link](https://github.com/rmsolgi/TensorLearn/tree/main/CP_decomposition) for a complete explanation and example.